# Flip vertical and horizental image with clip path and filter in svg

Tags: svg, flip

I am using an `SVG`.

Example:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="SvgjsSvg1000" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;left:0px;top:0px;"> 
 <g>
  <defs>
         <clipPath id="clipPathId">
         <rect width="200" height="200"></rect>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  <g>
  <image id="SvgjsImage1004" xlink:href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" clip-path="url(#clipPathId)" width="600" height="250"/> 
  </g>
 </g>  
</svg>
```

I would like to flip it horizontal and vertical. Can I get solution for this?

Comment: please can we have a [mcve] i.e. something that displays rather than markup that does nothing, and some description of what it would look like if it displayed as you wanted it to.

Comment: your `SVG` is not working!! and where do you want to flip it?

Comment: SVG is working now. Please be check it. Horizental and vertical flip

Comment: @Adam Can you help with this.

Comment: Try to add `transform: scaleX(-1);` to the SVG. Is that what you are looking for?